# Should the name of a capital Greek letter also be capitalized when the upper case is important?

Tags: mathematics, capitalization

In complexity theory, we sometimes have to speak about Knuth’s big omega notation. Or about Knuth’s big Omega notation? Here the confusion starts. I can imagine all four variants of "big/Big omega/Omega notation" and, if you like hyphens, all four variants of "big/Big-omega/Omega notation".  I am typesetting a main-body text (not a paper's title).

1. Which versions are correct, which are preferrable without a hyphen?
2. Which versions are correct, which are preferrable with a hypen?

For those who are interested: the notation, in Knuth's variant, is

Ω(f)   ≝   { g: naturals→naturals | ∃ real c>0  ∃ natural n  ∀ natural m≥n :  g(m) ≥ cf(m) } .

An aside: the little omega / little Omega function also exists, defined as

ω(f)   ≝   { g: naturals→naturals | ∀ real c>0  ∃ natural n  ∀ natural m≥n :  g(m) > cf(m) } .

Comment: When they are used in the title of a notation, book, film, or theory, &c., it is customary to capitalize all words except interior articles. The hyphens, it seems to me, are a matter of convention in the particular field.

Comment: When I write "title", I don't mean the "title" of a paper. I mean the _name_ of a thing. So _every_ use of the name _Big Omega_ should be capitalized. The title of Steinbeck's book is _The Grapes of Wrath,_ and every use should be capitalized; so also for _Big Omega._

Comment: @LeonMeier, hyphenated or unhyphenated, you should capitalize a name, for example Little-Endian and Big-Endian.  However, if you look around the internet you'll find little consistency in when to capitalize or not.  So go with what seems best to you.

Comment: The hyphens are a matter either of convention in the field or editor's choice. I'm not familiar with complexity except insofar as it applies to bass fishing.

Comment: I would capitalize both, but it's a matter of taste. Whatever you choose, though, be consistent.

Comment: @P.E.Dant -- Your comments would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is a good practice to treat the name of a thing—a notation, book, film, or theory, &c.—as a proper name. We capitalize such things in English, e.g.:

> The Grapes of Wrath
>   Star Wars: The Wrath of Khan
>   Theory of General Relativity
>   Big Omega notation

Note that here, it may be the convention within the field to *also* capitalize the *class* of thing named, in this case "notation".

Interior "small" words such as "the", "and", and "of" are usually not capitalized, but they *are* capitalized when they come first, e.g. "The Grapes of Wrath" above.

There are many examples of hyphenated titles of this kind, and  the usual convention seems to be that both terms are capitalized, as in *Big-Endian.*

Where hyphenation is concerned, that is also usually a matter of convention within a given field. If the field provides no such guidance, the writer or editor must decide; but any such decision to hypenate a term should always be applied consistently throughout the work.